# Find minimum and maximum from datetime coulmn in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a column called DateTime in my data set DT. I need to find the minimum and maximum value form this.

```
      DateTime
1/1/2018 13:03
1/1/2018 14:03
1/1/2018 13:15
1/1/2018 21:03
1/1/2018 20:03
1/1/2018 19:55
1/1/2018 13:03
```

Comment: What's the type of your DateTime column ? Please post the result of `dput(head(DT))`

Comment: What have you tried, see `min`, `max`, `summary`?

Comment: try: max(format(DT$DateTime, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")) and min() vice versa

Comment: you'll need to convert to a date format before you can sort. Something like  strptime(DateTime, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",tz = 'Europe/London')

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
a <- list("DT DateTime" = c("1/1/2018 13:03", "1/1/2018 14:03", "1/1/2018 13:15", "1/1/2018 21:03", "1/1/2018 20:03", "1/1/2018 19:55", "1/1/2018 13:03"))
a <- data.frame(a)
df <- as.POSIXlt(a$DT.DateTime, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Then you can use `min` and `max` on `df`